# Pass parameter to EventHandler

Tags: c#, event-handling, parameter-passing

I have the following `EventHandler` to which I added a parameter `MusicNote` music:

```
public void PlayMusicEvent(object sender, EventArgs e,MusicNote music)
{
    music.player.Stop();
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
    myTimer.Stop();
}
```

I need to add the handler to a `Timer` like so:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PlayMusicEvent(this, e, musicNote));
```

but get the error:

> "Method name expected"

EDIT: In this case I just pass e from the method which contains this code snippet, how would I pass the timer's own `EventArgs`?

Comment: The answers on the duplicate question suck though. The top response here should be the canonical answer.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

`Timer.Elapsed` expects method of specific signature (with arguments `object` and `EventArgs`). If you want to use your `PlayMusicEvent` method with additional argument evaluated **during event registration**, you can use lambda expression as an adapter:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => PlayMusicEvent(sender, e, musicNote));
```

**Edit:** you can also use shorter version:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => PlayMusicEvent(sender, e, musicNote);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I had to change the names of sender and e in the first set of brackets because they were the same as in the containing method. Could you please explain to me what they are? i.e. what's the difference between sender, e in the first bracket and the ones in the second?

Comment: `(sender, e) => PlayMusicEvent(sender, e, musicNote)` is anonymous method. Values in first brackets are actual parameter names and values in second brackets are actual parameters' usage. Think of it as short form for `void NONAME(var sender, var e) { PlayMusicEvent(sender, e, musicNote); }` where parameter names are inferred from context and `musicNote` is taken from local variables. This one line creates new method that uses your method and sets it as handler for timer's event.

Comment: And how to remove this `eventHandler`? `-=` does not work.

Comment: @EruRōraito http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995339/detach-event-handler-after-attaching-method-with-passed-parameter?noredirect=1#comment26312041_17995339

Comment: "**evaluated during event registration**".  Does this mean that the method is called at registration time, or that the method parameters are stored for execution as they were passed at registration time?

Comment: It's impossible to unsubscribe (as Yassine Houssni mentioned) from anonymous method in this case. To unsubcribe, you need to store event handler object (ElapsedEventHandler) somewhere and unsubscribe from exactly that instance.

Comment: I have menu items generated within a for-loop, and I want the handling method to be passed the int which I use to iterate through my loop. However, the int always becomes equal to the amount of iterations the loop has had and is thus out of bounds for my intent. Rather than 0 for the first, 1 for the second element, it will just be, say, 5 if my loop is `(int i=0; i<5; i++)` ...what do I do?

Comment: I still can't unsubscribe that method. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: I believe the event can be unsubscribed like so: `var event = new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => PlayMusicEvent(sender, e, musicNote));

myTimer.Elapsed += event;

myTimer.Elapsed -= event;`

Comment: For unsubscribing I would try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277053/4550701

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are calling a method instead of passing it as a parameter. Try the following:

```
myTimer.Elapsed += PlayMusicEvent;
```

where

```
public void PlayMusicEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    music.player.Stop();
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
    myTimer.Stop();
}
```

But you need to think about where to store your note.