# C# pass parameters to event handler

Tags: events, parameters, handler

A question that has come to my mind. Let's say I want to pass a variable theVar to the event handler declaration below

```
new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(evHandler)
```

and receive it in the definition below:

```
public void evHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: Is this your event handler (are you *invoking* the handler) or do you just want to use an object ("variable") with an existing event? That is, perhaps the signature for the handler would be better as [`void evHandler(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass parameter to EventHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/pass-parameter-to-eventhandler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the person writing the code that's raising the event, Mr. Hopkinson puts it very nicely in his answer.  You need a custom EventArgs with properties to represent the data you hope to pass.

But if you are merely consuming the event rather than raising it, your options are more limited.

Since you're anticipating receiving an AsyncCompletedEventArgs from your event, though, you do have one option:  the UserState propery of AsyncCompletedEventArgs.  This is a property you get to supply when you call the asynchronous method that ultimately causes the event to be fired.  It can be any object you choose.  You supply it when you call the async method, and the event returns it to you in the event argument properties when the method call completes.

Comment: Nice, I shall remember that one. Though hopefully I'd have wondered what userstate was when I embarked on my TonysAsynchCompletedEventArgs class.

Comment: Thanks for both approaches. I'll choose this answer since this scenario is more prevalent in my codes i.e I'm simply consuming the event.

Answer (score 1):

Define a descendant of EventArgs

e.g.

```
public class MySpecialEventArgs :EventArgs
{
   public int theVar {get; private set;}

   public MySpecialEventArgs(int argVar)
   {
      theVar = argVar;
   }

}
```

Then when you raise the event throw one of the above in instead of a EventArgs

When you add your handler e will be a MySpecialEventArgs.

Comment: I agree with this, but it assumes that you have control over the code that raises the event.

Comment: @AnnL More of a prerequisite than an assumption. Is there some nasty hack to avoid it?