# C# EvenHandler only updates once

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get more familiar with eventhanlders, but my current even only updates once, I want it to update until I close the application.

This is my code:

```
private static event EventHandler Updater;
Updater += Program_updater;
Updater.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
Application.Run();


private static void Program_updater(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    KeyUtils.Update();
    Framework.Update();
}
```

But like I said, it will only update once, I want it to update until I close my application. I know I can just do a While(true) but I rather not.

Comment: It should automatically update every time unless the object of the event changes.  You have a null object so it is getting called one.  Maybe try using 'this' instead of 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here:

```
Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
aTimer.Elapsed += Program_updater;

// Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
aTimer.AutoReset = true;

// Start the timer
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Specify callback:

```
private void Program_updater(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    KeyUtils.Update();
    Framework.Update();
}
```

Now every 2 seconds (or specify any other interval) callback `OnTimedEvent` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely normal that your event is fired only once because the application starts only once. 
What you acctualy need is to set up a timer and do some work on its tick.
Please have a look on example in answer for that question [Simple example of the use of System. Timers. Timer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337130/simple-example-of-the-use-of-system-timers-timer-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Well it only updates once since you only invoke it once (I don't really get the context where your code runs since you both declare a static variable and invokes it on the same scope which is impossible).

If you want something to occur *periodically* you should use [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), or in some cases [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`ManualResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

`EventHandler`s should be used only when you work as [event driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) which mean you want your handler to invoke ***When something happens***

Here an example for `[System.Timers.Timer][2]` with your handler:

```
//Invoke every 5 seconds.
Timer timer = new Timer(5000);

//Add your handler to the timer invocation list.
timer.Elapsed += Program_updater;

//Start the timer.
timer.Start();
```

Also you need `Program_update`'s signature to look like that:

```
private void Program_updater(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```