# Unsubscribe / remove Event Handler with custom arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, events, event-handling

I subscribe / create  a custom `Event Handler` with the following code:

```
myButton.Click += (sender, e) => MyButtonClick(sender, e, stuff1, stuff2);
```

I want to unsubscribe / remove and tried it like this:

```
myButton.Click += MyButtonClick;
```

But throws the following error:
`No overload for 'MyButtonClick' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'`

And like this:

```
myButton.Click += MyButtonClick(sender, e, stuff1, stuff2);
```

But throws the following error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'`

How do I unsubscribe / remove that same `Event Handler`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `Lambda` you need to keep a reference of it to unsubscribe.

Try this

```
RoutedEventHandler handler = (sender, e) => MyButtonClick(sender, e, stuff1, stuff2);
myButton.Click +=  handler;//Subscribe
//Some more code
myButton.Click -=  handler;//Unsubscribe
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your method does not match the signature of your event handler.  In your first example you are creating an anon method with the correct signature that calls your method and adding the anon method as the event handler.

If you no not like this approach then simple create a wrapper method that fulfills the signature and calls the other method, which is essentially what you are doing e.g.

```
public void MyButtonClickWrapper(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyButtonClick(sender, e);
}
```

You can then wire this up in the normal way:

```
myButton.Click += MyButtonClickWrapper
myButton.Click -= MyButtonClickWrapper
```

Comment: Thank you BenRobinson, your answer worked, but @SriramSakthivel's answer was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: this is the the default behavior, he is asking about using a custom event handler

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
EventHandler myEvent = (sender, e) => MyMethod(myParameter);//my delegate

myButton.Click += myEvent;//suscribe
myButton.Click -= myEvent;//unsuscribe

private void MyMethod(MyParameterType myParameter)
{
 //Do something
}
```