# How to add some parameters to WorkbookBeforeClose() event of Excel

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

**WorkbookBeforeClose** event of Excell Application has 2 parameters: **(Workbook Wb, ref bool Cancel)** . I want to add `Excel.Application excellApp` like third paramater into that event. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/pass-parameter-to-eventhandler) is the way to pass another parameter to event. I tried:

```
excelApp.WorkbookBeforeClose += new AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler((wb, c) => mamed(wb, c, excelApp ));
```

But I get error like **parameter 2 must be declared with the 'ref' keyword**. I also `added 'ref'` keyword, but there is not any result.

How can I sole this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the cancel parameter (c) with the ref keyword:

```
excelApp.WorkbookBeforeClose += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(
    (Excel.Workbook wb, ref bool c) => mamed(wb, c, wb.Application)
    );
```

Comment: One question please: my mamed() event return "object". What should I return there? In that method I do application closing operatrions only.

Comment: @JhoonBey - the return value is ignored, so if you're not using it anywhere else you can return anything (e.g. null), or change the method signature to void.