# C# .net, syntax for when calling a method how to pass in variable with method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I apologize if this is a pretty simple fix, as I am new to C#.
Here is a code snippet for monitoring a folder in Windows:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = label1.Text;

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                   NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                                   NotifyFilters.FileName |
                                   NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
"
            watch.Filter = "*.*";

            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged(label4));
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

As you can see, while I'm monitoring a folder for files being "Created", for each file it will execute the method `OnChanged`.

I have a label on my .net App, and I would like to pass that label text as a string variable into the `OnChanged` method.
My question is how do I pass in a variable into the OnChanged method?
It appears whatever syntax I have tried, including the above syntax Visual Studio 2010 is not liking it.

The onChanged method looks like this:

```
            public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e, String label4)
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
                String fileName = file.Name;
                String outputPath = label4.Text + file.Name;
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/pass-parameter-to-eventhandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass your argument directly, but you can use a lambda expression to wrap it.

```
watcher.Created += (source, e) => OnChanged(source, e, label4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression for this:

```
watcher.Created += (sender, args) => OnChanged(label)
```

[Some background on lambda expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1032182/Lambda-Expressions)