# Remove eventHandler that was added using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, eventhandler

I have a control that I added an event to. However, I needed to pass some extra parameters to the event method, so I use lambda expression like it was described here:

[Pass parameter to EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/pass-parameter-to-eventhandler)

```
comboBox.DropDown += (sender, e) => populateComboBox(sender, e, dataSource, selectedItem);
```

But this event should only fire the first time the conditions are met after what it should be removed.

Doing this doesn't work:

```
comboBox.DropDown -= (sender, e) => populateComboBox(sender, e, dataSource, selectedItem);
```

So the question is, is there a way to remove this method?

I've seen this:

[How to remove all event handlers from a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91778/how-to-remove-all-event-handlers-from-a-control)

But I can't get it working for ComboBox DropDown event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsubscribe anonymous method in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183367/unsubscribe-anonymous-method-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Also possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362204/how-to-remove-a-lambda-event-handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that it's not getting removed is because you're giving a new lambda expression when removing it. You need to keep the reference of delegate created by Lambda expression to remove it from the control.

```
EventHandler handler = (x, y) => comboBox1_DropDown(x, y);
comboBox1.DropDown += handler;
```

It will work simply like:

```
comboBox1.DropDown -= handler;
```

via reflection:

```
    private void RemoveEvent(ComboBox b, EventHandler handler)
    {
        EventInfo f1 = typeof(ComboBox).GetEvent("DropDown");
        f1.RemoveEventHandler(b, handler);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work because I need to remove the eventHandler from within itself, and this won't take itself as a parameter, since it's still unassigned. I could create a chain of events, but that is getting more complicated than I would like.

Comment: Why not keep the handler as class member or may be in named cache? Remove it when your conditions are met by accessing it as member or cached reference.

Comment: Fixed it. Created a handler beforehand with a dummy method, then wrote what you did there.