# C# Using variables in multiples functions for Windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, variables, radio-button

I would like to use a variable in multiple functions in Visual Studio. I'm trying to get  ***value_1***  to be used to show as a label for  ***private void button1_Click***.

If I try it this way I get this error message:

**'Black1_CheckedChanged' matches delegate 'EventHandler'**

What am I missing? 
I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int value_1 = 20;
    int value_2 = 20;
    int value_3 = 20;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Groupe Colour 1
    private void Black1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int value_1)
    {

        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

        value_1 = 0;
    }

    private void Brown1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;

        value_1 = 1;
    }

    private void Red1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        value_1 = 2;
    }

    private void Orange1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

        value_1 = 3;
    }

    private void Yellow1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

        value_1 = 4;
    }

    private void Green1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

        value_1 = 5;
    }

    private void Blue1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

        value_1 = 6;
    }

    private void Purple1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;

        value_1 = 7;
    }

    private void Grey1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

        value_1 = 8;
    }

    private void White1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        value_1 = 9;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value_1 = int.Parse(label_total.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(object sender, EventArgs e, int value_1)` should be `(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Also, nowhere are you assigning the value of `value_1` to the button's text.

Comment: Note that event handlers are effectively contracts that they accept certain parameters, you can't just change the parameters. Think of it like a lock and key, if they don't match, they don't work.

Comment: Declare your `int`s in your Class scope (under `public partial class Form1 : Form`). Then you can access their values anywhere in that class. Don't touch the event handlers declaration. They won't match the delegate form anymore.

Comment: @Jimi OP already has.

Comment: @john  HA. You're right. The indentation fooled me. They seemed to be declared along InitializeComponent();

Answer (score 0):

`Black1.CheckedChanged` expects a method of specific signature (with arguments `object` and `EventArgs`). The number of parameters for `Black1_CheckedChanged` function was changed. With more parameters than two parameters, the call to the function won't find the value for the third parameter `int value_1` and that error raises. That's why error is thrown.

> To solve that, you must change this part of your code:
>
> ```
> private void Black1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int value_1)
> {
>     colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>     groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>
>     value_1 = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> To this:
>
> ```
> private void Black1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>     groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>
>     value_1 = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Or, as you can see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8644281/9621052), you can use a lambda
>   expression as an adapter to your event handler and you can use your current
>   function without changes:
>
> ```
> Black_1.CheckedChanged += new CheckedChanged((sender, e) => Black1_CheckedChanged(sender, e, value_1));
> ```
>
> With the previous solution, your code will be like this:
>
> ```
> public partial class Form1 : Form
> {
>     int value_1 = 20;
>     int value_2 = 20;
>     int value_3 = 20;
>
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>         Black_1.CheckedChanged += new CheckedChanged((sender, e) => Black1_CheckedChanged(sender, e, value_1));
>     }
>
>     ...
>
>     private void Black1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int value_1)
>     {
>         colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>         groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>
>         value_1 = 0;
>     }
> }
> ```

If you need to pass a new parameter in a simple way, you can pass the value by other way, like using other variable in class scope (class property) to store the value you need.

> For example:
>
> ```
> public partial class Form1 : Form
> {
>     int value_1 = 20;
>     int value_2 = 20;
>     int value_3 = 20;
>     int temp = 0;
>
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     ...
>
>     private void Black1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         colour1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>         groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
>
>         temp = 0;
>     }
> }
> ```