# C# get EventHandler process information

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I start a few processes and I want to know which process called the OutputHandler, but I can’t get any information about the sending process. 
When I try to read a property, it always throws a InvalidOperationException

```
void ExecString()
{
    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = executeExe;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0}/{1}@{2} @{3}", parameter0, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;

        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
}   

void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs output)
{
    try
    {
        OutputText = output.Data;
        var tmpProcess = (Process)sendingProcess;
        var testId = tmpProcess.Id; // Throw Exception
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        OutputText = e.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the docs for the [Process.Id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This is a documented exception, thrown if there's no ID, either because it hasn't been set yet or because there's no process. Perhaps the path was wrong, or the argument resulted in an error?

Comment: After the process start I get a process id, in the output handler I get the data that I expect. Just the sendingProcess object has no expected information.

Comment: Add the argument you need to your OutputHandler method, like *Processs prc*.  And a lambda expression to subscribe the event so you can pass the *process* variable.  The *using* statement has to go, the process object need to stay alive until it terminates.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/pass-parameter-to-eventhandler

Comment: Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

string pid = Process.Id.ToString();

Could you try this and respond me please.@user2369332

Comment: I removed the using statement and now I can access the process information from the eventhandler. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: i think also my solution would help you :) did you ever try it. you are welcome. @user2369332

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this, It may help you;

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); 
var pid = currentProcess.Id;
```